# Print out a statement after 2 seconds

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it print out how long time has passed in seconds after 2 seconds. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
while(System.nanoTime()/1000000000<2){
System.out.println(System.nanoTime()/1000000000);
}
```

Comment: o.O What do you mean?

Comment: System.nanoTime() is an ever-increasing value from the startup of the JVM (maybe even an earlier point in time).  So, the while loop will only wait if executed at that very early point-in-time (not likely).  Subtracting two values returned by System.nanoTime() is a great, reliable means to find elapsed time though.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` should never be used as anything but tracking how long it takes for parts of your program to run. As it says in the documentation, the time it starts is not reliable, and it may even restart in the middle of your program if you're really unlucky!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Thread.sleep()` method to wait a number of milliseconds:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Two seconds have passed");
```

Comment: You're welcome :)

If this answer is helpful, after 10 minutes are so you can mark it as accepted. That way future visitors to the site can see what answers are helpful.

Comment: @nmelssx It takes like 10 or 15 minutes before you can, but there will be a little check mark under the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The "X" problem is the logic in the posted code is wrong - it doesn't consider when the operation was started, so it'll never know how long was waited. Consider the following code which, while not ideal here, is a *common* idiom when dealing with times and loops waiting for such to occur.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
while (true) {
   long now = System.nanoTime();
   long elapsed = now - start;
   if (elapsed >= (2 * 1000000000)) {
      // Yup, more than 2s between when we started and now.
      break;
   }
   // Otherwise, make toast (ie. make the CPU get hot)..
   // ..but we can help that a bit with a "yield" - run it with and without
   // the following line commented and view the CPU usage in a process monitor.
   Thread.sleep(0);
}
System.out.println("Time up!");
```